# Authorization in Google Cloud Endpoints for external clients

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

We are developing an API which is intended to be used by our external clients which are not inside Google Cloud.
It seems that Google Cloud Endpoints is a good candidate for such case.

What we need:

1. Client to be able to register in our "developer portal" to obtain necessary credentials.
2. To keep track of our clients (to see the number of requests of a particular client, to revoke his access to API, etc.)

The part which is not very clear to me is how to authenticate and identify our clients if they are not in Google Cloud.

We already use Firebase authentication by user email in one part or our application. It would be handy to continue using that authentication, but I am not quite understand how.
Google [docs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-firebase) say that client application must send a JWT token. But what private key does it have to use to sign the JWT?

The second option to authenticate client we are thinking of is to use [custom method](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-custom) to authenticate users. But I have the same question: What private key does the client application have to use to sign the JWT?

Is it intended that client generates its' own key pair?

If there are some better options for our use-case or if I am missing something, feel free to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right way!

- With firebase, the JS library allow you to authenticate to the correct identity provider and the lib also allows you to generate a JWT. No private key needed here!
- With custom method, it's different. Cloud Endpoint need to validate the signature of the JWT. For this, Cloud Endpoint need to know the public key of the private key used to sign the JWT. Most of time, it's provided by your own IdP system.

In your context, Firebase auth (or [Cloud Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs), if you want to manage your users on Google Cloud) is the best solution for you. *With several customers, you can't register all their public keys, the only one solution is to have your own IdP and all your customer registered on it.*

I have additional question: How do you plan to count the number of request per client? Through Cloud Endpoint or you own database?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will give it a try.  
Counting the number of requests in the Cloud Endpoints is fine for me.  
Maybe setting some request limit through Open API specification would be enough for me.

Comment: My question was more a warning than a question! I [wrote an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/rate-limit-your-api-usage-with-cloud-endpoints-quotas-1270da55d2bf), and you can't implement quotas and rate limit without API_KEYS. And to differentiate clients, you need to have 1 API Keys in different projects (1 per client). And you can't do it automatically by script and API Call, it's only a manual operation (there isn't API to generate API Key!). Not really developer friendly for now (for now because a new product is coming on this area ;) )

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere are you talking about https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/google-cloud-api-gateway-is-now-available-in-public-beta? are endpoints going to retire soon? how about ESPv2?

Comment: I don't know for endpoint. ESPv2 is used by API Gateway. It's the open source version. API Gateway is the managed version. I think that API Gateway and Cloud Endpoint will merge because the feature are the same and the limit between both isn't clear!

Answer (score 0):

We came up with a solution using [custom](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-custom) method to authenticate users:

1. We implemented user authentication by email using firebase (as stated in my question).
2. Added a way for users to upload their public certificate to our "portal".
   2.1. This was done using Google Cloud functions. Basically, we created a two endpoints:
   2.1.1. to upload public certificate using firebase token.
   2.1.2. to display all public certificates in JWKS format by some url (this way google is able to verify users JWT signature)
3. Published an instruction for users on how to form JWT to use our API (at this point every user have to have private key associated with their public key uploaded earlier).
4. Now users of our API are able to make API calls with JWT token provided.

Our technologies stack looks like following:

1. Cloud functions (for certificate handling).
2. Firestore (for authentication, storing certificates etc.).
3. Cloud Endpoints with [ESPv2](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine-standard)
4. Google App Engine standard environment